# How to run a pod each node in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to run an application on docker swarm, but a pod should run on each node. Because it has a lot of port forwarding. I couldn't find any information about this. How can I limit a pod on each node? Especially, I can configure easily in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker swarm we would deploy a `stack` containing `services`.

Defined in yaml, the deploy mode lets us specify that an instance (a `task`) of the service needs to be created on each node:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  example:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

`docker stack deploy --compose-file stack.yml test-stack`
`docker service ps test-stack_example`

will show that docker has deployed 1 service task to each node of the swarm.